# Classify a word to pre-defined topics with their definition

Tags: nlp, text-classification

I have several topics and I want to classify words that match these topics. For example:

Topic: "Wedding"

Definition: "A wedding is a ceremony where two people are united in marriage."

```
Input word     Score (assumed)
---------------------
husband         0.8
science         0.1
love            0.7
engage          0.9
...             ...
```

I am very new to topic classification. I don't know are there any method to use to solve this problem effectively?

Answer (score 0):

A simple and effective mechanism for classification is [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier). You can find several open source repos from where you can learn. Some examples are [NLTK Naive Bayes Classifier](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/naivebayes.html) or [Wink Naive Bayes Text Classifier](https://github.com/winkjs/wink-naive-bayes-text-classifier).

Comment: But how can I define the features from the definition? Should I use Word2Vec to define the relatedness between a given word and the definition (set of non-stopwords)?

Comment: I am not very clear about your question. However if you use simple bag of words model with NBC and train a corpus on different classes, then you will have, for example, P(love|marriage) — which will be much higher than the P(science |marriage); something like you have outlined in the table (word/score).